# I can't run this query, but when i simulate it in phpmyadmin, it returns the rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm going to delete some rows in one of my table called `sy_user`. I want to delete some of the rows that is not matched in the other table, which is the `tb_master_pegawai`.

How do i solve this query to do the row delete using the subquery as the `WHERE` condition?

I used subquery as the `WHERE` condition in the `DELETE` query.
 When i run it in phpmyadmin it says

> You can't specify target table 'sy_user' for update in FROM clause

But when i simulate it, it has return rows.

```
DELETE FROM sy_user 
       WHERE user_id NOT IN 
                (SELECT tbpeg.ID 
                 FROM tb_master_pegawai AS tbpeg 
                 JOIN sy_user AS tbuser ON tbpeg.ID=tbuser.user_id)
```

I expect the result is i have deleted the rows that are not matched with the same data in the other table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't reference your the table you are deleting from in a subquery of `DELETE`/`UPDATE` queries. Instead, use a `LEFT JOIN` and check where the joined table is `NULL` (meaning it had no rows that matched the `ON` condition).

Try to run delete queries within a transaction when testing it, that way you can rollback if the query deleted more rows than intended.

```
DELETE u
FROM sy_user AS u
LEFT JOIN tb_master_pegawai AS tp
  ON tp.ID = u.user_id
WHERE tp.ID IS NULL
```

Comment: *"You can't reference your the table you are deleting from in a subquery of DELETE/UPDATE queries."* Yes you can with a simple trick nest it one more time.. `WHERE user_id NOT IN 
                SELECT ID FROM (SELECT tbpeg.ID ...) a` , then MySQL should allow this but a LEFT JOIN should perform better vs a corelated subquery..

Comment: Ugh, nesting selects to cheat, not my preferred way of doing it :D You're right though, if I'm not mistaken, it only checks the first subquery and not sub-subqueries.. But I'd avoid that and use a `LEFT JOIN` instead. So its not entirely wrong to say you can't use subqueries - but you can use sub-subqueries.

Comment: True very true.. ANSI/ISO ideally should add something to the SQL specs more or less like a `FOREIGN [RELATION] CHECK(expression/query)` to make updates/deletes depend on possible other tables but thats mine opinion

Comment: Oh, I agree. Ensuring data integrity through foreign keys is quite neat (and handy!).

Comment: I do not understand the question. Can you help me with it? @Qirel

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify your request using only a LEFT JOIN:

```
DELETE sy_user FROM sy_user
LEFT JOIN tb_master_pegawai ON sy_user.user_id = tb_master_pegawai.ID
WHERE tb_master_pegawai.ID IS NULL
```